# Get ffmpeg to output frames closer to start time specified

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffmpeg-filters

I'm running `ffmepg` version 6.1 with the following command:

```
ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -copyts \
    -ss 2841000000us \
    -to 2843000000us \
    -i <INPUT_FILE/URL> \
    -fps_mode passthrough \
    -an \
    -filter_complex "[v:0]fps=fps=4[t1];[t1]showinfo[out6]" \
    -map [out6] "C:\\temp\\ffmpeg\\regions_%06d.bmp"
```

Note: ☝️ is simplified, there are many more filters after the `fps`/`showinfo` filter in the `filter_complex` parameter.

Of interest:

- I am using the `showinfo` filter, as I want to be able to get the timestamp of the frames that are being processed
- I only want to process four frames per second, hence the use of the `fps` filter
- `copyts` is specified so that the output of `showinfo` is relative to the entire video, not just the start of what is processed
- `fps_mode passthrough` so that frames are not dropped/duplicated

When I run this, I get the following output from `showinfo`:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 000002247a51c900] config in time_base: 1/4, frame_rate: 4/1
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 000002247a51c900] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 000002247a51c900] n:   0 pts:  11624 pts_time:2906    duration:      1 duration_time:0.25    fmt:yuv420p cl:left sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:5EF9BE12 plane_checksum:[0EA20F02 7B431A80 7DCB9490] mean:[85 135 144] stdev:[41.5 17.1 29.3]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 000002247a51c900] color_range:tv color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
```

The output seems to indicate that the first frame has a timestamp of 11624 pts (which is 2906 seconds, or 48 minutes and 26 seconds).

This is *way* off from the start time indicated: 2841000000us (2841 seconds, or 47 minutes and 21 seconds).

I suspect this may have something to do with the format.  The relevant output on `stderr` is:

```
mime type is not rfc8216 compliant
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Skip ('#ID3-EQUIV-TDTG:2023-11-16T13:37:57')
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-TWITCH-ELAPSED-SECS:0.000')
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Skip ('#EXT-X-TWITCH-TOTAL-SECS:21820.003')
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Opening 'https://d1mhjrowxxagfy.cloudfront.net/c335467319186f0ab945_darumaisgod_40800750599_1700120047/chunked/0.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0000027c77fd2dc0] Opening 'https://d1mhjrowxxagfy.cloudfront.net/c335467319186f0ab945_darumaisgod_40800750599_1700120047/chunked/1.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://d1mhjrowxxagfy.cloudfront.net/c335467319186f0ab945_darumaisgod_40800750599_1700120047/chunked/index-dvr.m3u8':
  Duration: 06:03:40.00, start: 64.001000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
  Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
```

But when I try a different video type I get:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'https://rr5---sn-8xgp1vo-ab5d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1703316710&ei=hjiGZYmWM6SP_9EPmtCYoAg&ip=96.250.109.72&id=o-AFKWMi6Avd7t8alGkE4l3B1AbzCBNApprFJAz720_n2G&itag=303&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=LW&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-8xgp1vo-ab5d%2Csn-p5qddn7z&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=5&pcm2cms=yes&pl=20&initcwndbps=1283750&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=6064827915&dur=14618.036&lmt=1699818339689953&mt=1703294953&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=IOS&txp=730F224&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJfQdSswRQIgR_40aset9xfHYzBZGZ8TlrnHj4npZGEE5wnCp8b5JZsCIQDL0Tfk_Mfe0D-cR3qrv1Vm2o4A10ddPOq0qw7ehLRCbg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AAO5W4owRgIhAMVzisKgq6dFqEX3-XW9xxpD-1Wl44B3kZp9rImtC3SyAiEAhItXuk4kkG7pzNUm97sMZQ2twFYo2pG7kq3orIfUbCw%3D':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : google/video-file
  Duration: 04:03:38.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3319 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
```

And `pts_time` for the first frame is *exactly* 2841 (or, 47 minutes and 21 seconds, the start time specified).

I suspect I am doing something wrong/inefficient here when it comes to the first format type, is there a way to get the the frames to output closer to the start time specified in this scenario?